# Different CPUs with same rating perform vastly differently... what is going on?

Tags: cpu, raspberry-pi, cluster, ansible

I built a cluster out of 6 OrangePi Zero's, which each have an H2+ Allwinner 1.2GHz quadcore CPU, 256MB RAM, and a 16GB class 10 Patriot SD card. They are connected via 100Mb ethernet switch and controlled by a raspberry pi head node. I am communicating with each compute node using Ansible, which just allows me to easily issues commands over SSH, and there are no daemons or anything running on the compute nodes.

So, Each compute node is a fresh install of Debian server, and are identical. However, a simple execution of `sysbench` benchmarking, in which I stress the CPU finding prime numbers, results in different finishing times by up to 50%. In other words, I issue the same command to these identical 6 systems, and they finish at different times. Why is this?

I've installed `cpufrequtils` and have changed the governor to `performance` and specified the max CPU frequency identically on each node.

If anyone has any insight whatsoever, please let me know, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Now you know why they are cheap!

Comment: I'm actually really impressed with these little guys. It was my fault they were overheating. I am very happy with my $7 purchase, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple... I realized it was due to poor case design. 2 of the 6 compute nodes were slower than the rest, and they were also closer to the PSU. After adding a fan, all nodes operated at the same speed. Wow!